# Run command on local build, but not TFS build

Tags: batch-file, tfsbuild, post-build-event

My post-build event is:

```
"$(DevEnvDir)TF.exe" checkout "$(TargetPath)"
```

This checks out the target build assembly file. This is what I want, and it works great in VS.

On the build server, `$(DevEnvDir)` is equal to `*Undefined*`. So, I modified my post-build event to the following:

```
IF NOT "$(DevEnvDir)" == '*Undefined*' "$(DevEnvDir)TF.exe" checkout "$(TargetPath)"
```

The problem is, it still evaluates to see if `$(DevEnvDir)TF.exe` is an executable, and on the build server it evaluates to `*Undefined*TF.exe`, which throws this error:

> '"*Undefined*TF.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

How can I conditionally execute this statement without it evaluating if the executable exists first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a command conditionally like this, use PowerShell:

```
if ('$(DevEnvDir)' -ne '*Undefined*') { [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start('$(DevEnvDir)TF.exe', 'checkout "$(TargetPath)"') }
```

And wrap it in a clean PS environment:

```
powershell -windowstyle hidden -nologo -noprofile if ('$(DevEnvDir)' -ne '*Undefined*') { [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start('$(DevEnvDir)TF.exe', 'checkout "$(TargetPath)"') }
```